# Importing excel file with php to mysql how to getting/adding and inserting columns dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, import-from-excel

For example, if in one file there are three columns

```
id name city
```

and in the second file, there are 4 columns

```
id name city state
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can export the Excel in CSV, you can use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` SQL statement. But you will need to read first the first line of the csv, which should contain the exact SQL table field names and use that to identify, which columns/fields you have to update from this file.

This way you are able to load the columns dinamically.